# SSIS For Loop Container Runs Successfully But Data Flow Tasks and Scripts Inside of the Loop Intermittently Run

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, foreach-loop-container

I've done some research on SO but having a tough time finding a solution (it might be the way I am searching), so please direct me to an appropriate post if you know of one. I am also by no means an SSIS guru.

I have an SSIS For Loop that always completes successfully, but the various data flow and script tasks inside of the loop intermittently run (they all do run successfully sometimes, but when they don't run, they are left with no indicator that they ran...no green/red/yellow checkmarks, just blank). It seems like the evalexpression in the loop is being interpreted incorrectly. If I rerun the package manually in VS, sometimes it returns data and sometimes it doesn't. This package is deployed to an SSISDB and the SQL Server Agent Job runs successfully each night, but again, intermittently returns or doesn't return the previous days data.

The loop is setup based on dates. The initexp assigns it yesterday's date, the assign expression increments the date variable by a day after it runs successfully, and then should evaluate to false. See image

[image: forlooplogic]

The `@begindate` variable's expression is

```
= dateadd("d",-1,getdate())
```

Here is an image of the For Loop and the items inside of it. In case it matters, the tasks inside are just going out and hitting an api, storing the result in a variable, and then process it via various script tasks.

[image: forloopcontents]

Any advisable next steps for troubleshooting? Anything I am overlooking / missing?

Picture of successful run with no data with variable information

[image: successnodata]

Comment: The SSIS db location and system time would matter. Is it a local server?

Comment: @user10454145 can you post an image of when it doesn't run? Do all unable to run? If you add logging, what do you see in it?

Comment: @ShivSidhu yes it is a local server, thanks for asking, I forgot to include that in the post. It is properly interpreting the dateadd expression (e.g. it returns the 13th of March when I run it for today, March 14th)

Comment: @Arthur posted a pic to the OP. I disabled other packages but they all do something similar. Pasted a link to an image that shows the For Loop container executing successfully and then what the variables are populated with at run time. Not sure what other logging you'd like to see?

Comment: I can see you have a breakpoint set this is why the execution stops @user10454145

Comment: @Arthur I only set the breakpoint for troubleshooting

Comment: @user10454145 then how does it help see what packages ran versa not?

Comment: @user10454145 is the issue solved? have you tried the provided answer? if so why not giving a feedback or accepting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use @[System::StartTime] instead of GETDATE()

Since `GETDATE()` is a function which is evaluated each time it is called, it may cause some issues if you use it inside a for loop expression.

Using `dateadd("d",-1,GETDATE())` in the Eval expression means that it **is dynamic and doesn't contains a fixed value**.

You can benefit from [the system variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-2017) `@[System::StartTime]` which contains the datetime of the package execution. The expression used to evaluate `@[User::begindate]` will be:

```
= dateadd("d",-1, @[System::StartTime])
```

**InitExpression**

```
@startdate = @begindate
```

**EvalExpression**

```
@startdate <= dateadd("d",-1,@[System::StartTime])
```

*Note that if `@[System::StartTime]` and `@StartTime` didn't worked in the expression then add a new variable of type `DateTime` and Evaluate is as expression `= @[System::StartTime]` then use this variable in the EvalExpression.*

**AssignExpression**

```
@startdate = dateadd("d",1,@startdate)
```

Comment: I've implemented this approach...I'll report back with any success. If my job returns data successfully tonight and tomorrow I'll come back and mark this as the solution, thank you!

Comment: Seems to be working, never would have guessed getdate() would cause such issues. Thank you!